# How to make point in second window jump to line number specified at point of first window

Tags: emacs, emacs24

I have two buffers split side by side. The first window has an error log which contains  line numbers with some error codes. e.g.

```
ERROR: CHSDFT: <description> in foo.v, line 200|0
```

I have opened `foo.v` in the second window. Now I recall reading about a nifty shortcut in emacs which works as follows. If I have the error log buffer in focus and my point is on top of the value 200, if i execute a keystroke, the point will move to line number 200 in the second buffer. Unfortunately I forgot the keystroke and after much Googling I still haven't found it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it. Its `C-u M-g M-g`
The description [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Select-Buffer.html) says:

```
Read a number n and move to line n in the most recently selected buffer other than the current buffer.
```